# Auto billing using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  try to auto bill calculation  but, I didn't get how to the auto bill. when I entering  cost, when show on the price input field but I didn't get how to display the total price in total filed without using button, please can any can help me .
Here my code

```js
function calc(idx) {
 var cost = 0;
 var qty = 0;
 var del = 0;

 var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost" + idx).value)
  + parseFloat(document.getElementById("del" + idx).value)
  + parseFloat(document.getElementById("qty" + idx).value);

 document.getElementById("price" + idx).value = isNaN(price) ? "0.00" : price.toFixed(3);
}

function totalIt() {
 var qtys = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
 var total = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i <= qtys.length; i++) {
  calc(i);
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price" + i).value);
  total += isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
 }

 document.getElementById("total").value = isNaN(total) ? "0.00" : total.toFixed(3);
}


window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
 document.getElementsByName("cost[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
 document.getElementsByName("del[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
};

var rowCount = 0;

function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "checkbox";

 element1.name = "chk[]";
 cell1.appendChild(element1);

 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var element3 = document.createElement("input");
 element3.type = "text";
 element3.name = "item[]";
 element3.required = "required";
 cell3.appendChild(element3);

 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var element4 = document.createElement("input");
 element4.type = "text";
 element4.name = "qty[]";
 element4.defaultValue = 0;
 element4.id = "qty" + rowCount;
 element4.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell4.appendChild(element4);

 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 var element5 = document.createElement("input");
 element5.type = "text";
 element5.name = "cost[]";
 element5.value = 0;
 element5.id = "cost" + rowCount;
 element5.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell5.appendChild(element5);

 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 var element5 = document.createElement("input");
 element5.type = "text";
 element5.value = 0;
 element5.name = "del[]";
 element5.id = "del" + rowCount;
 element5.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell5.appendChild(element5);

 var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
 var element6 = document.createElement("input");
 element6.type = "text";
 element6.name = "price[]";
 element6.id = "price" + rowCount
 cell6.appendChild(element6);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
 } catch (e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="bg-info">

         <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-danger">Add your Products</h3>
         <input  class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add Item " onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

            <input class="btn btn-Dark" type="button" value="Delete Item" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       

            <table id="dataTable" >
        <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:15px;">Select</th>
        &nbsp;
        <th style="padding-right:15px;">Sr. No.</th>
        
        <th>Item Name</th>
    
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>gst Tax</th>
        <th>delivery charges</th>
        <th formula="cost+qty+del"summary="sum">Price</th>
        
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="item[] "/> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text"   Value =0 id="qty1" name="qty[]"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text"  Value =0 id="cost1" name="cost[]" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text"  Value =0 id="del1" name="del[]" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="price1" name="price[]" /> </td>  
                </tr>   
               
            </table>
             <br/>
             <div class="total" style="text-align:right;padding-right:80px;" >
          Total: <input  class="btn btn-Dark" type="text" readonly="readonly"name="total[]"  onkeyup="totalIt()"id="total" /><br/><br/>
         <input  class="btn btn-Dark"type="button"  value="Total" onkeydown="totalIt()" /> &nbsp;<input  class="btn btn-success"type="submit" />
             
        </div>

          </form>   </div> </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
               <script>      
</script>
```

Comment: use `onInput` event handler

Answer (score 1):

Update parameter in `function calc(idx, iscallTotalit)`. Add condition in function `if (!iscallTotalit)`. Update`calc(i, true);` in totalit() function.

**Edit**

`document.getElementById("cost" + idx).value || 0` Added `|| 0` at the end so if the value is null or empty then it will replace it with 0.

```js
function calc(idx, iscallTotalit) {
 var cost = 0;
 var qty = 0;
 var del = 0;

 var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost" + idx).value || 0)
  + parseFloat(document.getElementById("del" + idx).value || 0)
  + parseFloat(document.getElementById("qty" + idx).value || 0);

 document.getElementById("price" + idx).value = isNaN(price) ? "0.00" : price.toFixed(3);

 if (!iscallTotalit)
     totalIt();
}

function totalIt() {
 var qtys = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
 var total = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i <= qtys.length; i++) {
  calc(i, true);
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price" + i).value || 0);
  total += isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
 }

 document.getElementById("total").value = isNaN(total) ? "0.00" : total.toFixed(3);
}


window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
 document.getElementsByName("cost[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
 document.getElementsByName("del[]")[0].onkeyup = function () {
  calc(1)
 };
};

var rowCount = 0;

function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var element1 = document.createElement("input");
 element1.type = "checkbox";

 element1.name = "chk[]";
 cell1.appendChild(element1);

 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var element3 = document.createElement("input");
 element3.type = "text";
 element3.name = "item[]";
 element3.required = "required";
 cell3.appendChild(element3);

 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var element4 = document.createElement("input");
 element4.type = "text";
 element4.name = "qty[]";
 element4.defaultValue = 0;
 element4.id = "qty" + rowCount;
 element4.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell4.appendChild(element4);

 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 var element5 = document.createElement("input");
 element5.type = "text";
 element5.name = "cost[]";
 element5.value = 0;
 element5.id = "cost" + rowCount;
 element5.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell5.appendChild(element5);

 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 var element5 = document.createElement("input");
 element5.type = "text";
 element5.value = 0;
 element5.name = "del[]";
 element5.id = "del" + rowCount;
 element5.onkeyup = function () {
  calc(rowCount);
 };
 cell5.appendChild(element5);

 var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
 var element6 = document.createElement("input");
 element6.type = "text";
 element6.name = "price[]";
 element6.id = "price" + rowCount
 cell6.appendChild(element6);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 try {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowCount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
 } catch (e) {
  alert(e);
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="bg-info">

         <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-danger">Add your Products</h3>
         <input  class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Add Item " onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

            <input class="btn btn-Dark" type="button" value="Delete Item" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       

            <table id="dataTable" >
        <tr>
        <th style="padding-right:15px;">Select</th>
        &nbsp;
        <th style="padding-right:15px;">Sr. No.</th>
        
        <th>Item Name</th>
    
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>gst Tax</th>
        <th>delivery charges</th>
        <th formula="cost+qty+del"summary="sum">Price</th>
        
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="item[] "/> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text"   Value =0 id="qty1" name="qty[]"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text"  Value =0 id="cost1" name="cost[]" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text"  Value =0 id="del1" name="del[]" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="price1" name="price[]" /> </td>  
                </tr>   
               
            </table>
             <br/>
             <div class="total" style="text-align:right;padding-right:80px;" >
          Total: <input  class="btn btn-Dark" type="text" readonly="readonly"name="total[]"  onkeyup="totalIt()"id="total" /><br/><br/>
         <input  class="btn btn-Dark"type="button"  value="Total" onkeydown="totalIt()" /> &nbsp;<input  class="btn btn-success"type="submit" />
             
        </div>

          </form>   </div> </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
               <script>      
</script>
```

Comment: thank you Bhargava  for code, when I am deleting one column values its  0 but  i want to add two columns values please help me how to do

Comment: Updated my Ans Please check @martonmarsuri

Comment: Thank you   very much Bhargav Aboti

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to handle the input directly:

```js
const $source = document.querySelector('#source');
const $result = document.querySelector('#result');

const typeHandler = function(e) {
  $result.innerHTML = e.target.value; //Here you can handle the event, make your calculation and display the calculated data
}

$source.addEventListener('input', typeHandler) // register for oninput
$source.addEventListener('propertychange', typeHandler) // for IE8
```

```html
<input id="source" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: hi  Olli it is did not working properly.can  show to its work please.